# Typescript variable with type and undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
interface Data {
   name: string,
   address: string
}

interface Detail {
   detail: Data | undefined
}

export const Profile: Detail {

   profile: undefined

}
```

Here I have initially defined `profile` as `undefined`. It works fine. I can update prifle with `Data` type.

What I want to achieve here is at some point I should be able to update `profile` with `undefined`.

I can initialize with `undefined` but I can not update it with undefined.

How can I make it to take either `Data` type or `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an = sign, the last three lines should be

```
export const Profile: Detail = {
    profile: undefined
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like:

```js
interface Data {
   name: string;
   address: string;
}

export const Profile = {
   profile: Data | undefined;
}
```

I couldn't really understand the usecase of `Detail` interface.